# Making a left sidebar appear under a right hand column on a mobile with bootstrap 3

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a layout where the sidebar is on the left. This isn't a problem on desktop browsers. However, when it's resized to mobile, the sidebar appears above the main column.

The problem is illustrated at http://bootply.com/89871

Does anyone know how to get them to swap? I'd prefer a CSS solution if possible.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

There may be a better way to do this, but here is what I would do:

```
<div class="container"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 side hidden-sm">
        Left (Side) - Move content to Partial View
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 main">
        Right (Main) - Should be first when Mobile 
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 side visible-sm">
        Bottom - Load content from Partial VIew
       </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

What I did:

1. Add a class `hidden-sm` and `visible-sm` to hide the first div and make the third div visible when it is a mobile device.  You may want to change the classes to adjust for tablets if needed.
2. I would recommend moving the content of the left side bar to a partial view and then load that partial in both divs.  This way you don't have duplicate content.

### Update

This way is better:

```
<div class="container clearfix"> 
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-8 col-md-8 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 main pull-right">
        Right (Main) - Should be first when Mobile 
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 side pull-left">
        Left (Side) - Move content to Partial View
      </div>
    </div>    
</div>
```

What I did:

1. Add `clearfix` to `container div` since we are floating divs
2. Make the Right Content first in the markup
3. Add `pull-right` and `pull-left` to float the content where it should be

Comment: Wouldn't loading it in 2 left divs (1 hidden, 1 not) still have duplicate content? This was my idea initially, but I was worried about having duplicate content.

Comment: The content would be loaded on the screen twice, but you would only have to update the content in one spot (the partial view).  I'm about to update my answer again to suggest another thing, which I think may work.

Comment: @dotty look at my update.  I think the second way should work.

Comment: Very concise and helpful

Answer (score 10):

The cleaner approach would be using Bootstrap's native column ordering classes.

"Easily change the order of our built-in grid columns with .col-md-push-* and .col-md-pull-* modifier classes."

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-md-9 col-md-push-3">.col-md-9 .col-md-push-3</div>
  <div class="col-md-3 col-md-pull-9">.col-md-3 .col-md-pull-9</div>
</div>
```

Will result in the left column appearing on the right and the right on the left.

Source: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid-column-ordering

Comment: Thanks, this is by far the best solution!